# No DWARF information found

Tags: kernel, debugging

I saw this error in dmesg:

```
abrt-hook-ccpp: Failed to create core_backtrace: dwfl_getthread_frames failed: No DWARF information found
```

Is that a config problem? Do I need to install something to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, DWARF (= Debugging With Attributed Record Formats, [see this link for more details](https://developer.ibm.com/technologies/systems/articles/au-dwarf-debug-format/)) is a type of debugging information embedded into an executable program.

Sometimes, to minimize disk space use and/or to avoid disclosure of the program's internal workings, this debugging information may be stripped away, or not added in the program in compilation time in the first place.

So the message probably means that a program was crashing but the `abrt` subsystem failed to create a call backtrace listing from the crash state because the necessary debug information was not available.

If the program that is crashing is commercial software, the debugging information might be available for the software vendor's own development team only. In that case, the best you can do is to find the core dump information collected by `abrt` and send it to the software vendor for further analysis.

But if it's open-source software, it might be possible to install a separate debug information package corresponding to the software package that contains the failing program. That might allow `abrt` to generate the backtrace (i.e. a sort of "how did we get here?" information) if the program crashes again. You might even be able to use the debug information to generate backtraces for older crashes from which `abrt` has saved the core dump information, if the core dump is still available.

But if you are not a programmer and have no interest in trying to understand the internal workings of whichever program seems to be failing in your system, you can certainly ignore the message.